# How to take a date from the user?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I go about designing a Python program which takes in a date from the user, a date that looks like this 3/13/17, and turns it into a date which looks like this 2017.3.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string by using the `str.split` method like this:

```py
s = "3/13/17"
month, day, year = s.split("/")
print(f"20{year}.{month}.{day}")
```

Python will automatically assign the splitted values to the variables month, day, and year

Comment: Depending on the desired behavior, it may make sense to blow up if the user provides an invalid date like `a/b/c`.  In that case it would be better to use a package like `datetime` to parse and format the date for that extra layer of validation.

Answer (score 1):

Get the date as text and then convert it to date with the format you would like. or get the date as a number (month, date and year ) separately and make it as a date.
Example:

```
my_string = str(input('Enter date(yyyy-mm-dd): '))
my_date = datetime.strptime(my_string, "%Y-%m-%d")
```